# when i am trying to copy a local directory to remote server directory

Tags: apache, scp, remote-server

When I am trying to copy a directory from local machine to remote server directory,It is asking for remote server password but i dint set any password for that.How should i solve it??

Answer (score 0):

Have you test to enter login (session name) without password.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have set a password, even if when you use that remote server physically it logs in automatically, your user account will still have a password. Do you mean you're trying to use an ssh key with no passphrase?

Comment: I have sought out that problem but the problem I'm getting now is that how should i traverse in directory on local machine,copy the folder and paste in target folder directory of remote server..Should i enter the ip address of local mamchine or just the path of folder will work

Comment: @sanchitjain If you have solved the problem (even if the problem was not what you thought it was originally), you should add an answer and explain what you have learnt. That will help other people.

Comment: Roger that..The problem was that i was entering the wrong ip address for my server. When i entered the correct ip address of my server,it worked.So can you solve my query?

Comment: You will need to enter an address for either your local machine or the remote server. If you are logged in on your local machine, you copy the file to your server with: `scp localfile username@yourserverIP:path/to/destination`. If you are on the remote server (and your local machine is accessible from there), `scp username@localmachineIP:/path/to/file destination_folder`

Comment: If i'm on my remote server how can i access local machine from there??

Comment: When I'm trying to enter address of my local machine with source file path and target folder path of remote server.I'm getting error "Error Connecting:network unreachable"